# java String != null not working reading from bufferedReader

Tags: java, string, nullpointerexception, bufferedreader, numberformatexception

In android I am getting the String value from BufferedReader and it is null after reading from file.

```
intstring = br.readLine();
System.out.println(intstring);
if(intstring != null)
{
      System.out.println("Inside if condition");
      int istring = Integer.parseInt(intstring);
}
```

My output is

```
 null
 Inside if condition
 NumberFormatException
```

Help me please

Comment: @ThusithaThilinaDayaratne:  `.equals()` isn't necessary to check for `null`.

Comment: Is it really `null`? Or just "null"?

Comment: Use equals() method.Read more about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Comment: Check your file or input...i think it's giving "null" as input...which is valid string and string != null will be true for this case.

Comment: might be output have characters as "null" its a string. Cross check once.

Answer (score 1):

Your `NumberFormatException` is happening because your input isn't a number.  Maybe it's a blank line, or maybe it has  some non-numeric characters.  In fact, your output suggests that it's actually the word `"null"`.

You've got some options.

- You could check that the string contains digits and no other characters before you parse it, for example by using a regular expression and a condition like `if (intString.matches("\\d+"))`.
- You could catch the `NumberFormatException`, and do something particular when it happens.
- You could check whether your string is blank, if you knew that there weren't going to be any non-numeric characters in the input.  For this option, you might write `if (!intString.equals("")))`.

Comment: In the code its printing as null , if you see the output he provided, so there is no chance of getting non numberic character or etc.

Comment: So, most likely it's actually the word `"null"`.  Four non-numeric characters.

Comment: The input from where he is reading might has characters as "null" .

Comment: @developer - Is there an echo in the room?  He just said that :-)

Comment: The bufferedReader store the value of String as "null" and not null if br.readLine() is empty

So try checking

(!Stringval.equalisIgnoreCase("null"))

instead of

(Stringval != null) or (Stringval.equalsIgnoreCase(null))